# Write list into one column of a csv file

Tags: java, csv

I need an approach on how to write a list as a column into a csv file.

I have a class which has data stored in its data members.
Class looks like this

```
public class Final_object {
public String reporttype;
public List<String> metric_name=new ArrayList<String>();
public List<String> id=new ArrayList<String>();
public List<String> name=new ArrayList<String>();
public List<String> type=new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

I need to write each list as a column into a csv

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: No, i dont know how to approach for this situation

Comment: I could use some code snippet

Comment: try https://www.callicoder.com/java-read-write-csv-file-opencsv/ and post once you stuck up at some point

Comment: i am stuck in the same place. OpenCsv has List<String[]> but i have List<String>.

Comment: `String str; String[] arr = new String[]{str}` - EASY

Answer (score 2):

## *Apache Commons CSV*

Use the [*Apache Commons CSV*](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) library, for reading/writing files in various flavors of [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) and [Tab-delimited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab-separated_values) formats.

Adding this to your class should do the job:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVPrinter;

//...

public void writeCsv(String outputFilePath) throws IOException {

    if(this.metric_name.size()!=this.id.size()
            || this.id.size()!=this.name.size()
            || this.name.size()!=this.type.size()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("ArrayLists backing CSV columns have mismatched size.");
    }

    try(CSVPrinter csv = new CSVPrinter(Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(outputFilePath)), CSVFormat.DEFAULT)) {
        //csv.printRecord("metric_name","id","name","type"); //uncomment if you want a header row
        for (int i = 0; i < this.id.size(); i++) {
            csv.printRecord(this.metric_name.get(i), this.id.get(i), this.name.get(i), this.type.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```